# Generalization of gradient calculation for multi channel convolutions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to understand how backpropagation for conv nets is implemented at mathematical level. I came across [this](https://grzegorzgwardys.wordpress.com/2016/04/22/8/) article which explains gradient calculation graphically for 2D convolution. The `conv layer consists of 3x3 inputs` and the dimension of the `filter used is 2x2` which, on convolution `results in 2x2 layer` which is then fully connected. `The gradient` for this fully connected layer will be of dimension `2x2`.
According to the article :-

```
Gradient of conv layer = convolution between gradient of next layer 
and weights of this layer
```

But I cannot generalize this for 3 channel inputs.
Lets say out input layer is of dimension `3x3x3` and we use 1 filter of dimension `2x2x3` then the resultant convolution will again be of dimension `2x2` which will then be treated as fully connected layer. 
Now the `gradient for fully connected layer will be 2x2`. So, to calculate the gradient for conv layer we again to calculate the `convolution between 2x2 gradient layer and 2x2x3 weight layer but they are incompatible` .

**So, I dont understand how to use this formula for calculating gradient for 3D convolutions. How can I proceed after this step ?**

Derivation(or an article) with respect to 3D input will also be really helpful .

Comment: convolving 3x3x3 with 2x2x3 should result in 2x2x1, not 2x2

Comment: @lejlot Yeah it will be 2x2x1 but still ,If you convolve each of the 3 channels of filter(2x2x3) with gradient of next layer(2x2x1) separately, you get a 1x1x3 tensor, but the dimension of gradient of a layer should be equal to the dimension of the layer itself, i.e, 3x3x3 and not 1x1x3.